# I want to append items to a list from an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, mapping

Here is my unordered list that I am trying to append additional list items to.

```
<ul id="subreddits">
   <li class="my-subs"><strong>MY SUBREDDITS</strong></li>
 </ul>
```

Here is the javascript. I tried two methods. I tried to map the array and also use a function. I get an error saying that it cant append to something null. *The variables in the array all have values which equal to their names as strings.*

```
 const subReddit = [home, "-", popular,"-", all, "-", random, "-", users]

function subredditList() {
 const unorderedList = document.getElementById("subreddits");
 for(let i = 0; i < subReddit.length; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = subReddit[i];
    unorderedList.appendChild(item);
}
}

subReddit.map((sub, index) => {
 const unorderedList = document.getElementById("subreddits");
for(let i = 0; i < subReddit.length; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = subReddit[i];
    unorderedList.appendChild(item);
}
})
```

Thanks in advance for the help. I really appreciate you all.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] that illustrates the error you're running into? Your code looks OK

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: That's not a [MCVE]. Likely the problem is addressed in the linked canonical.

Comment: I apologize I didnt click the link that explained it. You were right though, had I posted a  better example I couldve found out that the issue was that I put my script tags at the top of my HTML file. That link helped me as well.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your subreddit list, you don't need to store the `-`.

You can print a list with `join` specifying the separator (as shown below).

Clean your list then cycle over it, create li elements, and append them to the container as below:

```js
const subReddit = ['home', 'popular', 'all', 'random', 'users'];
console.log(subReddit.join('-'));

const container = document.querySelector('#subreddits');
subReddit.forEach(sub => {
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.innerHTML = sub;
  container.appendChild(item);
});
```

```html
<ul id="subreddits">
  <li class="my-subs"><strong>MY SUBREDDITS</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. It didnt work because I put my script tag at the top of my HTML. But this is way cleaner code. Thank you!! This will help